# How to implement a Dead Letter Queue using AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-sqs, serverless-framework, dead-letter

I'm trying to implement a dead letter queue for failed lambda events. I created an SQS queue and two lambdas. One lambda only throws an error and the other listens to the SQS queue and is triggered when the queue receives a message and logs the event to Cloudwatch.

In the AWS management console, I am able to see that the .function lambda (the one that throws an error) has a dead letter queue configured.

I am able to see that the .dispatcher function (the one that listens to SQS) is configured correctly and if I send a message to the SQS queue I can also see Cloudwatch logs showing it's being triggered as expected.

Although everything seems to be configured correctly, I am unable to get the .function to send an event to SQS when it's failed in order to trigger the .dispatcher lambda.

I've watched multiple videos, read documentation and I have not been able to figure out why this is not working. I've also tried the onError configuration but, no luck there either.

`handler.js`

```js
module.exports.function = async (event) => {
    throw new Error('Throwing error ')
}

module.exports.dispatcher = async (event) => {
  try {
    console.log(`Dispached Event:${JSON.stringify(event)}`)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return error
  }
}
```

`serverless.yml`

```yaml
service: dlq-example

frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        # Allow functions to list all buckets
        - Effect: Allow
          Action: '*'
          Resource: '*'

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-lambda-dead-letter

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.function
    description: Throws error.
    deadLetter:
      targetArn:
        GetResourceArn: DeadLetterQueue

  dispatcher:
    handler: handler.dispatcher
    description: Dispatcher function. Configured to be triggered by events sent to SQS and handle them.
    events:
      - sqs:
          arn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - DeadLetterQueue
              - Arn
resources:
  Resources:
    DeadLetterQueue:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        QueueName: dlq
```

Here are images of what I see in the AWS management console:

[Screenshot of handler.function lambda (the one that has the DLQ configured)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOJaW.png)

[Screenshot of the handler.dispatcher function (The one that listens to SQS and handles each message)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysjvV.jpg)

[Screenshot of the SQS queue and the lambda trigger configuration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5eVG.jpg)

Comment: " see that the .function lambda" - see where exactly? Your question is not clear and lacks details. How do you invoke the function? What are the SQS permissions? lambda permissions, and more info is missing.

Comment: I am able to see in the AWS management console both functions are created. I am also able to see in the AWS management console that the handler.function lambda has the the created SQS queue configured as it's dead letter queue. I can also see that my SQS queue is configured to trigger the handler.dispatcher function on each message however, when I invoke the handler.function lambda in the test console, I do not see the failed event being sent to the configured dead letter queue. Does this answer your question @marcin

Comment: Maybe it would be better to provide some screenshots of your lambda and sqs setup.

Comment: @Marcin I updated the post with screenshots. Thank you for responding so quickly! I hope this gives you the information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles across this issue in the future. My configuration was correct, I was missing a SQS queue policy. Once I configured a policy everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me, there might be disconnect in understanding on how the DLQ behavior works for Lambda.

---

First and foremost, DLQ feature in AWS Lambda is only available for triggers which are [**invoked asynchronously**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html#invocation-dlq) like S3, SNS, IOT etc

For the event source AWS SQS, Lambda polls the queue and invokes Lambda function [**synchronously**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) with an event that contains queue messages.

Hence setting a DLQ on lambda for event source of SQS would not work, it would never be triggered by lambda.

---

From the context of your problem, I think, what you are trying to achieve are:

```
1. Have a mechanism to capture SQS messages which fails to process in lambda function. (Preferably to a designated DLQ)
2. Have a mechanism to re-process these failed message using a different lambda function.
```

---

---

Assuming my understanding of the premise of this problem is correct, you may follow below steps to achieve it.

SQS queue provide a feature where if the consumers of SQS fails to process the message for a certain number of times, [These failed message can be moved to DLQ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html). (These DLQ can be configured at primary queue level).

You can follow your existing pattern and create a trigger on this DLQ to process the failed messages from the dispatcher lambda. [You may use this helpful guide to set these up](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/enhanced-dlq-management-sqs/).

In this approach, you are configuring DLQ at Queue level instead on lambda.

---

I hope this would help you in your design.